# how use localstorage in todo app (javascript)

Tags: javascript, local-storage

How can I use the storage property in the following code?
This code does not work properly and disappears after each refresh.

Please check my code in the link below
https://jsfiddle.net/74qxgonh/

```
let values = [];

// TAG Form ( give text)
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  // create object  (unique id)
  storageValue = {
    id: "num" + Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000, 9000)),
    text: e.target.elements.textInput.value,
  };

  //create Array for save to localStorage
  values.push({ storageValue });
  localStorage.setItem("values", JSON.stringify(values));
  
  //create Tags
  let input = document.createElement("input");
  input.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
  input.setAttribute("class", "chk-box");
  input.setAttribute("id", `${storageValue.id}`);

  let label = document.createElement("label");
  label.textContent = `${storageValue.text}`;
  label.setAttribute("for", `${storageValue.id}`);
  label.setAttribute("class", "chk-label");

  const btnDeleted = document.createElement("button");
  btnDeleted.setAttribute("class", "btn-delete");
  btnDeleted.textContent = "X";
  btnDeleted.addEventListener("click", () => {
    div.remove();
  });

  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.setAttribute("class", "inputGroup");
  div.appendChild(input);
  div.appendChild(label);
  div.appendChild(btnDeleted);

  document.querySelector(".container-center").appendChild(div);

  e.target.elements.textInput.value = "";
});
```

Comment: Are you sure the items disappear? You don't seem to ever get the data from localstorage in the first place.

Comment: You are using `localStorage.setItem()` to save data, but you never use `localStorage.getItem()` to load the data from the storage, so it's not clear to me what you expect to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably just need to replace the first line of your script to actually [get](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) the previously saved items from `localStorage` instead of starting with an empty array every time the app loads:

```js
// before
let values = [];
```

```js
// after
let values;

try {
  values = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('values')) ?? [];
}
catch {
  values = [];
}
```